# Qué estoy poniendo mal?

Tags: javascript

```
addBook(book, autor) {
          // El método 'addBook' recibe un string 'book' y un string 'autor' y debe agregar un objeto:
          // { nombre: book, autor: autor} al arreglo de libros del emprendedor.
          // No debe retornar nada.

          // Tu código aca:
          this.libros.push(book,autor);
        }
```

Comment: Gracias, lo probaré de esa manera.

Comment: ¿Cómo resuelve esto la duda del OP (autor de la pregunta)? Puede que la respuesta sea útil para tal usuario/a, pero otros miembros de la comunidad podrían ver el código y no comprender su funcionamiento. Pulsa en [edit] y explica brevemente _qué hace este código_. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que pasa es que `this.libros` es un array, por lo que veo, si usas `push(book, autor)` estás añadiendo al array el parámetro `book` y `autor`, mientras que lo que te piden es añadir un objeto con las propiedades de `book` y `autor`

```js
this.libros.push({nombre:book, autor});
```

Comment: Como bien dice @Rodrigo Ramirez, tendrías que añadir al array de ```libros``` un objeto como el que te está mostrando. Otra opción es crear un map de clave valor, pero no lo veo funcional, lo mejor sería añadir un objeto dentro.

Comment: Muchas gracias.